# Hamilton equations of motion for matter fields coupled to general relativity in ADM formalism

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, klein-gordon-equation, classical-field-theory, adm-formalism

1. Do you know what are the Hamiltonian formalism analogs of the Klein-Gordon equation and/or the Maxwell equations in general relativity?
2. Showing how these equations of motion for matter in the Hamiltonian formalism reproduce the known results from the Lagrangian formalism will be welcome.

Comment: You are invited to compute them.